# How can I get Visual Studio intellisense for the relative path

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, javascript-intellisense

I'm using `app-module-path`  [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) and project structure is like below:

```
- app 
  - ComponentA
  - ComponentB
- index.js
```

and in `ComponentA`:

```
const b = require('app/ComponentB');
```

but b is not recognised by VS Code intellsense.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I added a `jsconfig.js` at the root of project and it worked!

`jsconfig.js`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./"
    }
}
```